# Pink Flower Identification

Tags: identification

Do you recognize this spring blooming [image]pink flower with delicate foliage planted in the fall as a small corm? Tuber?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add where in the world this little darling is growing? And for all new users I recommend you take a moment to take the [tour] and browse through the [help], to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: Rose Valley, PA

Comment: https://mywildflowers.com/identify.asp  Does it help?

Comment: I got Geranium molle as a possibility, but the petals are arranged wrong and more importantly the leaves are very wrong. I do recognize it but can't remember its name (It's considered a weed where I live, IIRC). Not a bad key, but a database is limited to only the data in it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably Cutlead Geranium, *Geranium dissectum*, which is an introduced plant from Europe. We find it in lawns sometimes in Wisconsin. It's relatively identical to Carolina Geranium (*Geranium carolinianum*, a native species), but that one's petals seem wrong to me. Both are found in Pennsylvania.

A good source for you to look at:

Virginia Tech's [Weed Identification](https://weedid.cals.vt.edu/profile/203) site (be sure to click the arrows next to the photos on the top of the page to scroll through samples; some will match what you have). This site also gives identifying characteristics that you can use to verify my ID.

Once you've made a tentative ID, an excellent source for determining whether a plant is native or not and where in the US it has been reported is the US Dept of Agriculture's [Plant Finder](https://plants.usda.gov/home) site. You can enter either the scientific name or the common name.